# At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name

Tags: r

Hi can anyone please advise I am getting this error in my code thankyou using GBM method

At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name

```
set.seed(123)
indexes <- createDataPartition(gbmtrain$lada,
                           times = 1,
                           p=0.7,
                           list = FALSE)

    gbmtr<-gbmtrain[indexes,]
    gbmte<-gbmtrain[-indexes,]


gbmtr$lada<-as.factor(gbmtr$lada)
gbmte$lada<-as.factor(gbmte$lada)

View(indexes)

prop.table(table(gbmtrain$lada))
prop.table(table(gbmtr$lada))
prop.table(table(gbmte$lada))
set.seed(123)

train.control<- trainControl (method = "repeatedcv",
             number = 10,
             repeats =  3,
             summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
             classProbs = TRUE,
             search = "grid")
set.seed(123)
caret.cv<-train (lada~.,data = gbmtr,
                  method="gbm",
                  metric="ROC",
                  tunelength=40,
                  verbose= FALSE,
                  trControl=control,
                  preProcess=c("center", "scale"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please post your error message and your code?

Comment: caret.cv<-train (lada~.,data = gbmtr,
+                       method="gbm",
+                       metric="ROC",
+                       tunelength=40,
+                       verbose= FALSE,
+                       trControl=control,
+                       preProcess=c("center", "scale"))

Comment: Error: At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  X0, X1 . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).
>

Comment: have coded in caret and used MLP and Random Forest and didnt get the error message

Comment: Than it is pretty clear that the problem has to do with the GBM. What are you exactly using? Again, please paste your code into your OP.

Comment: Hi have posted all the code in above OP I am using R studio caret